# Count the number of sequences in a range

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to count the number of sequences in a dataset.
A new sequence is started whenever a the value changes from zero to positive or from positive to zero.

The data represent mm rain one entry for every hour of the day.
If it starts raining a new sequence starts, if it stops raining a new sequence starts as well.
On some days it keeps raining (1 sequence of rain, 0 sequences of dry).
On others days it will be dry (0 sequence of rain, 1 sequence of dry).
The other days will have X sequences of rain and Y sequences of dry (X and Y differ 0 or 1).

Example:
Range (N1:N25) contains

```
RH
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
3
9
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Using Matrix formulas I can calculate
The longest sequence of non-zero's, being 4, by

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF($N$2:$N$25>0,ROW($N$2:$N$25)),IF($N$2:$N$25<=0,ROW($N$2:$N$25)))
```

but i cannot calculate the number of sequences of non-zero's, being 2, nor the total number of sequences, being 5.

How can I do that?

I looked for the answer on Stackoverflow but couldn't find it

Comment: Hi, if I will be you, I would simply detect in O2 if N1 = 0 and N2 > 0 so you add O1 + 1 and may be add a special condition if N1> 1 so it is 1 in O1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count of non `0` groupings:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF($N$2:$N$25<>0,ROW($N$2:$N$25)),IF($N$2:$N$25=0,ROW($N$2:$N$25)))>0))
```

To get the count of `0` groupings:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF($N$2:$N$25=0,ROW($N$2:$N$25)),IF($N$2:$N$25<>0,ROW($N$2:$N$25)))>0))
```

then you can add them together.

Comment: What does the -- in the formula's do? Why is it there?

Comment: it changes numbers stored as text or booleans to their numeric equivalents.